# Upload image in react native and Express

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, multer

I use expo document picker to pick a file, and multer in the back end to save it into a folder.

When I send the image, I get a 200 status response but the image is not saved.

What have I been doing wrong ?

React native code :

```
const pickPicture = async () => {
    let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({});
    console.log(result.file);
    console.log(result);

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("avatar", {
      uri: result.uri,
      type: result.type,
      name: result.fileName,
      file: result.file,
    });


    axios
      .post(
        `http://localhost:8000/uploadAvatar`,

        data,

        {
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
          transformRequest: (infos, error) => {
            return data;
          },
        }
      )
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
      });
```

Node code :

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destintion: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, "avatars")
  },

  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
      callback(null, Date.now() = path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
    
});

const upload = multer({storage: storage});

app.use("/uploadAvatar", upload.single("avatar"), (req, res) => {

  res.status(200).json("Image enregistrée !")
})
```

Comment: try to change localhost:8000 to your own localhost ipv4 address.

Comment: the api handles the request because it returns the json response

Answer (score 0):

Path of the image to upload `result.file` returned by DocumentPicker is a reference of the image to the device storage not actually image data.

It required to fetch raw image data as BLOB and upload  BLOB data to the server.

```
let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({});
    console.log(result.file);
    console.log(result);

  const imageData = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      resolve(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
      reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
    };
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.open("GET",result.file, true);
    xhr.send(null);

  });



const data = new FormData();
    data.append("avatar", {
      uri: result.uri,
      type: result.type,
      name: result.fileName,
      file: imageData,
    });
```